# Set and get sessions

Tags: php, session

I am trying to set a php session from my loginpage:

```
if($results){
            $session->setId($results['Id']);
}
```

In my session class I have these:

```
    class Session{

        public function createSession(){
            session_start();
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

        }
        public function getId(){
    return $_SESSION['Id'];
}

public function setId($value){
            $_SESSION['Id'] = $value;
        }

        }
```

Then I try to call it to the index my Id

```
$thisSession=Session::getId();
if(isset($thisSession)) { 
   echo "The session is set."; 
} else{ 
   echo "Sorry, it's not set."; 
}
```

How can I do it?

```
Undefined index: Id
```

To pass the session id from login to my index page!

Comment: Are you even starting a session in all your different pages?

Comment: yes I am when I do `Session:::createSession();` it says that the session has already started

Comment: @jeroen it says `Undefined index: Id`

Comment: show us results dump please

Comment: @Hooli `array(24) { ["Id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" ["UserName"]=> string(5) "admin" [1]=> string(5) "admin" ["Password"]=> string(32) "21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3" [2]=> string(32) "21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3" ["UserType"]=> `

Comment: thx,  what is `$thisSession->Session::getId();` ? what do you expect for such a line ?

Comment: this line is weird: `$thisSession->Session::getId();`, either `getId()` is defined as a static function and you'd use `$idVar = Session::getId();`, or it's an instance function and you'd use `$thisSession = new Session(); $idVar = $thisSession->getId();`, but i see no reason to use both in the same line. For the rest, if there is no call to `setId()` at one point, using `getId()` will return `Undefined index`

Comment: its an error I forgot to update here its not -> but =

Comment: You can't call setID with `$session->setId($value)` and call the getter as static, it will just not work

Comment: okay can you please tell me how to do it.thnx @Hooli

Comment: I make an answer

Comment: @Hooli I need it today if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for sure create an object that encapsulate the `$_SESSION` but be careful about how PHP works.

I suggest small modifications to your class (if it's ok to you) using the session_id method :

```
class Session 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            $this->initSession();
        }
    }

    protected function initSession()
    {
        session_start();
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $this->setSessionId();
    }

    public function setSessionId()
    {
        $_SESSION['Id'] = session_id();
    }

    public function getSessionId()
    {
        return $_SESSION['Id'];
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that $_SESSION variables are accessible by users easily don't put in it too much informations, especially sensitive.

`$_SESSION` is a PHP superglobal variable you can retrieve it wherever your want to, but you can get it by declare :

```
$session = new Session();
$id = $session->getSessionId();

var_dump($id);
```

For logout you should add this method :

```
public function deleteSession()
{
    session_destroy();
}
```

And then use  when disconnected action is asked

```
$session =  new Session();
$session->deleteSession();
```

Comment: `Call to protected method Session::initSession() from context`

Comment: Why do you call it as static ??? Forget all about static in this context and use new Session.

Comment: one last question I cant logout

Comment: Ok wait a minute

Comment: `include "session.php"; 
Session::logOut();
@header('location:login.php');`

Comment: not static => use new Session() again. I edited my answer for your logout issue

Comment: `$session = new Session();
$id = $session->deleteSession();` nope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169350/discussion-between-hooli-and-ora).

Comment: I cant get the user Id with this session

Comment: please how can i get the id,its returns a long string